# How can I load test a JupyterHub instance?

Tags: jupyter, load-testing, locust, jupyterhub

We have several JupyterHub instances we use for training purposes. Frequently, we discover problems only when 30+ students are logged in, so we'd like a solution for automated testing. We'd like to log in, then run notebooks in parallel. Thanks.

I've toyed with doing this by hand using the requests package, but the right html commands to load and submit cells of a notebook are not obvious. Can Locust or some other tool do what I'd like to do? I'd like to see examples, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try recording a session in your browser and converting it into a locustfile using https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/har2locust

That should work reasonably well, assuming the calls are regular HTTP/REST calls (I dont really know JupyterHub so I’m kind of guessing)